# How do I import to a Subversion local repository in NetBeans 8.0?

Tags: svn, netbeans

I have downloaded CollabNet Subversion Edge 4.0.5 and created a local repository. The online info says I should be able to import my project into a repository with the right-click menu choice, "Versioning > Import into Subversion Repository." (This from https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html.) But "Versioning" does not appear on my project's right-click menu. I've clicked pretty much everything else, and that only confuses me further. For example, if I click "Subversion/Commit..." and proceed beyond the first dialog box, it says, "Authentication failed" and asks for the user/password for a repository with the URL, "https://svn.java.net/svn/jinput~svn," which is certainly not my local repository. It won't let me change the URL, either.

If I click "Checkout..." I do see the URL for my repository which is:

```
http://xps-8700/svn/DFL2
```

but there's nothing to check out and, when I select "trunk" (which is empty), it says, "org.apache.subversion.javahl.clientexception: svn: e155000: 'c:\users\smiller\documents\netbeansprojects\trunk' is already a working copy for a different url; perform update to complete it"

I uninstalled NetBeans 8.0 and reinstalled it, but that had no effect that I can see.

How do I import my project into a local Subversion repository? (Thanks for any help!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this answer from Ondrej Vrabec at http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=60031:

> c:\users\smiller\documents\netbeansprojects\trunk is already under svn
>   control, you must have made a previous checkout of another repository 
>   (looks to be https://svn.java.net/svn/jinput~svn) into the folder.
>   So either create you project somewhere else or remove all svn
>   checkouts   from trunk, netbeansprojects or any of their ancestor
>   folders. There   must be a .svn folder in one of them.

Finding and removing the .svn in the NetbeansProjects ancestor folder solved the problem.

Thanks, Ondrej!